# Docopt - Errors, exit undefined - CLI interface for Python programme

Tags: python, command-line-interface, docopt

I'm sure that the answer for this is out there, but I've read the site info, I've watched the video they made and I've tried to find a really basic tutorial but I can't. I've been messing about with this for most of the day and It's not really making sense to me.

Here's my error:

```
vco@geoHP:~$ python3 a_blah.py "don't scare the cats" magic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a_blah.py", line 20, in <module>
    arguments = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docopt.py", line 579, in docopt
    raise DocoptExit()
docopt.DocoptExit: Usage: 
    a_blah.py <start>... <end>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a_blah.py", line 33, in <module>
    except DocoptExit:
NameError: name 'DocoptExit' is not defined
```

line 20 - I don't see why that line is creating an error, it worked before and I've seen that exact line in others programmes?

I don't know why the line 570 of docopt is creating an error - I've seen others use DocoptExit(), isn't this something that's just part of Docopt? Do I have to write my own exit function for this? (I've not seen anyone else do that)

here's the code

```
import docopt

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        arguments = docopt.docopt(__doc__)

        print(arguments['<start>'])

        print("that was that")

        print(arguments['<end>'])       

    except docopt.DocoptExit:
        print("this hasn't worked")
```

What I'm trying to make this for is a script that I've written that moves files from one place to another based on their extension.

So the arguments at the command line will be file type, start directory, destination directory, and an option to delete them from the start directory after they've been moved.

I'm trying (and failing) to get docopt working on it's own prior to including it in the other script though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you want is in `docopt`'s namespace. You never import it into your global namespace, so you can't refer to it simply with it's name. You need to import it separately or refer to it through the module. You also shouldn't use parenthesis after the exception.

```
import docopt

try:
    # stuff
except docopt.DocoptExit:
    # other stuff
```

or

```
import docopt
from docopt import DocoptExit

try:
    # stuff
except DocoptExit:
    # other stuff
```

Comment: Cheers Roger, I actually had that setup originally, can't remember why I changed... But that parts working now thanks, It prints 'this hasn't worked' which is what I told it to (not sure if there's a built in error message)  I'm still not sure how to add multiple compulsory arguments though. I've updated the code to how It currently looks

Comment: @user3130747 It's probably best if you leave the code as it originally was. Changing it will confuse anyone else coming here afterwards with a similar question. If you have other questions related the code, it is best to make a new question and describe the new issue there.

Comment: Oh right, good point... The questions were part of the OP though, I'm struggling to work out how to set up the arguments, should I make another post for this? Cheers

Comment: @user3130747 I suggest reverting the code to how it was and perhaps editing the question to be specifically about the `DocoptExit` error. That's how I read the question at least. Then making a separate question about the other issue, with specific examples of how you tried to accomplish it and issues you've been having.

Comment: Agreed with Roger. I didn't even realize you were having other issues until I read this comment, @user3130747

Comment: no worries will do roger, meant to make it more concise rather than ambiguous by putting it all in here, thanks for the suggestions...In light of the edit I felt this was a decent answer, cheers

Comment: @AdamSmith No worries, guess I worded it a bit poorly! I'll stick to single purpose posts for now ;)